# asm - what is a local common area and difference between .lcomm and .comm?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm still a beginner in assembly language, and I want to understand what do the directives `.lcomm` and `.comm` mean in fact ?

I did a search in google, and found that `.lcomm` stands for local common, but I really don't understand what is that. Can someone clarify it please ?

Comment: You should not google, you should read the [manual for your assembler](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html). Basically both allocate zero-initialized storage from `.bss` section, but `.lcomm` keeps it private.

Comment: unfortunately, they don't explain what is a local common

Comment: What other explanation do you need? It's zero initialized storage from `.bss` section, which is not visible to other modules.

Comment: @Jester: thank you, I thought it was something special or specific ..

Comment: I guess lcomm tells that data are static in "c" equivalent.

Comment: The equivalent of C static data that does not have an initializer (so defaults to 0 by definition), or, has an explicit initializer whose value is zero (this last depending somewhat on the compiler / language implementation, as there is no requirement by the C standard to put explicitly zero initialized data in .bss even though it can).

Answer (score 3):

When a Unix process is run, it has an area called [bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) which is usually initialized to zero. Both .comm and .lcomm locations are allocated in bss. A .comm symbol is marked as global while a .lcomm symbol isn't.

If you have two files with the same symbols marked as .lcomm they will refer to *different* memory locations in bss. On the other hand, if you have two files with the same symbol marked as .comm they will refer to the *same* memory location in bss.